# How to override method from mixin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I'm working in some ruby code. There's a module like the below:

```
module ResourceTransformation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def import(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

In one of the classes that uses this module, I would like to override the `import` method. My current code looks like this:

```
class SomeEntity < ApplicationRecord
  include ResourceTransformation

  def import(resource)
    puts "in overriden import method!!!"
    # super
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I call `SomeEntity.import` it is simply invoking and returning the results from the module `import` method rather than from the class `import` method...

How can I properly override the module method with my class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`class_methods`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-class_methods) in your concern define class methods from given block

That's why you need override not instance but class (`self`) method

```
class SomeEntity < ApplicationRecord
  include ResourceTransformation

  def self.import(resource)
    puts "in overriden import method!!!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm - for some reason this isn't working for me :/

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams did you restart console / server before test it?

Comment: Ah! That was it - I needed to restart `rails console` lolz. Thank you @mechnicov!